Lebesgue Point Theorem with summability index $p \neq 1$

Definition: We say that $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ is a p-Lebesgue Point for $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ if the following holds:
$$
\lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y) - f(x)|^p \mathop{dy} = 0 .
$$

Theorem 7.7 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis states that if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ then $f$ admits 1-Lebesgue Points almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Thus I would like to know if, starting from this Theorem, we can show that the same holds for $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and p-Lebesgue Points. I tried doing some manipulations but I feel stuck and I am not sure that we can use this Theorem in order to obtain the desired result because intuitively we would need an inequality which is the reversal of Holder Inequality (and thus false in general).

Any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself more clearly.

I assume the integral is dy?

@spinosarus123 Yesm I am sorry and thank you for pointing it out!

Let's take the proof from the French Wikipedia page for Lebesgue's differentiation theorem (which should be close to the one in Rudin's book if my memory serves me well) and tweak it so as to prove the desired result, as it doesn't seem easy to derive it from the version for $p = 1$ directly.
Let $1 \leq p < +\infty$. (I know barely anything about $L^p$ spaces when $0 < p < 1$ so I won't open that can of worms...)
Define the following functions for $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$: $$T_{p,r}(u) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n \,\longmapsto\,\left(\frac{1}{\lambda(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} |u(y) - u(x)|^p \mathrm{d}y\right)^{\frac1p}$$
and:
$$T_p(u) : x \,\longmapsto\, \limsup_{r \to 0^+} T_{p,r}(u)(x)$$
What we want is then to show that $T_p(f)^p$ is almost everywhere equal to $0$, and to do that it suffices to look at $T_p(f)$ instead.
By density of continuous functions in $L^p$, there exists for all $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$ a continuous function $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that: $\|f - g_k\| \leq 1/k$. Name $h_k$ the function $f - g_k$.
Using the triangle inequality in $L^p$, we then have:
$$T_{p,r}(f)(x) \leq T_{p,r}(g_k)(x) + T_{p,r}(h_k)(x)$$
so that:
$$T_p(f) \leq T_p(g_k) + T_p(h_k)$$
Yet, as $g_k$ is continuous, we have $T_p(g) \equiv 0$: indeed, for some fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can find $\delta = \delta(x, \varepsilon) > 0$ such that if $0 < r \leq \delta$ then $|g_k(y) - g_k(x)| \leq \varepsilon$ for $y \in B(x,r)$, in which case this yields:
$$T_{p,r}(g_k(x)) \leq \left(\varepsilon^p \frac{\lambda(B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))}\right)^\frac1p = \varepsilon$$
On the other hand, we have, again with the triangle inequality in $L^p$:
$$\begin{split}T_{p,r}(h_k)(x) &\leq \left(\frac{1}{\lambda(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} |h_k(y)|^p \mathrm{d}y\right)^{\frac1p} + \left(\frac{1}{\lambda(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} |h_k(x)|^p \mathrm{d}y\right)^{\frac1p}\\
&\leq \left(M(|h_k|^p)(x)\right)^\frac1p + |h_k(x)|\end{split}$$
where $Mv$ for $v \in L^1$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $v$, i.e.:
$$Mv : x \in \mathbb{R}^n \,\longmapsto\, \sup_{r > 0} \frac{1}{\lambda(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} |v(y)|\mathrm{d}y$$
This means that we get:
$$T_p(f)(x) \leq \underbrace{T_p(g_k)(x)}_{=\, 0} + T_p(h_k)(x) \leq \left(M(|h_k|^p)(x)\right)^\frac1p + |h_k(x)|$$
Let's now consider some fixed $c > 0$ and prove that $\{T_p(f) > c\}$ is negligeable.
By the previous argumentation, we have the inclusion: $$\{T_p(f) > c\} \subseteq \left\{M(|h_k|^p) > c^p\right\} \cup \{|h_k|^p > c^p\}$$
However, we know (it's proved before the $p = 1$ theorem at least in Rudin) that: $$\lambda\left(\left\{M(v) > d\right\}\right) \leq \frac{3^n \|v\|_{L^1}}{d}$$
for $v \in L^1$ and $d > 0$, and that:
$$\lambda(\{v > d\}) \leq \frac{\|v\|_{L^1}}{d}$$
so that, for $v = |h_k|^p$ and $d = c^p$:
$$\lambda\left(\left\{M(|h_k|^p) > c^p\right\} \cup \{|h_k|^p > c^p\}\right) \leq \frac{(3^n + 1)\overbrace{\||h_k|^p\|_{L^1}}^{= \|h_k\|^p_{L^p}}}{c^p} \leq \frac{3^n + 1}{c^p k^p} \xrightarrow[k \to \infty]{} 0$$
Taking the limit when $k$ tend to $\infty$ provides the expected negligeability of $\{T_p(f) > c\}$.
This is true for all $c > 0$, thus $\{T_p(f) > 0\} = \bigcup_{c \in \mathbb{Q},\, c > 0} \{T_p(f) > c\}$ is negligeable  as a countable union of neglieable sets, and $T_p(f)$ is equal to $0$ almost everywhere, meaning that, indeed, almost every point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $p$-Lebesgue point of $f$, with $f$ being an arbitrary function of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
